# Problem connecting to Hsqldb via Hibernate when running a Eclipse GWT project

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt, hsqldb

I'm trying to run a simple GWT project where I'm trying to do a simple persitence via hibernate to a HSQLDB database. The database I'm using I have been using for at least 2 years with several osgi applications without any problems. So all I done is reused the same configuration and added a simple object mapping file. The problem I have is that I get a socket creation error when ever I try to persist the object with in GWT jetty. I now the database is up and running, I can telnet to it, run OSGI projects that uses the same config with out problems. This is the stack I get when running

```
25 [21704474@qtp-26509496-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Hibernate 3.3.1.GA
30 [21704474@qtp-26509496-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - hibernate.properties not found
34 [21704474@qtp-26509496-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Bytecode provider name : javassist
42 [21704474@qtp-26509496-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
162 [21704474@qtp-26509496-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - configuring from resource: hibernate.cfg.xml
162 [21704474@qtp-26509496-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Configuration resource: hibernate.cfg.xml
268 [21704474@qtp-26509496-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Reading mappings from resource : hbm-mappings/project.hbm.xml
382 [21704474@qtp-26509496-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder - Mapping class: se.kanit.projectmgr.db.ProjectDAO -> T_PROJECT
419 [21704474@qtp-26509496-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Configured SessionFactory: null
3534 [21704474@qtp-26509496-0] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
3534 [21704474@qtp-26509496-0] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - Hibernate connection pool size: 1
3534 [21704474@qtp-26509496-0] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - autocommit mode: false
3537 [21704474@qtp-26509496-0] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - using driver: org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver at URL: jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:1476/dirtyharry
3537 [21704474@qtp-26509496-0] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - connection properties: {user=sa, password=****}
3594 [21704474@qtp-26509496-0] WARN org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Could not obtain connection metadata
java.sql.SQLException: socket creation error
 at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
 at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcConnection.(Unknown Source)
 at org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver.getConnection(Unknown Source)
 at org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:154)
 at org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProvider.java:133)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:111)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2101)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1325)
 at se.kanit.projectmgr.db.HibernateUtil.(HibernateUtil.java:24)
 at se.kanit.web.projectmgr.server.issues.IssuesService.addIssue(IssuesService.java:26)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:100)
 at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:562)
 at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:188)
 at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:224)
 at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:713)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:806)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
 at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:51)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
 at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
 at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:122)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
 at com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:70)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
 at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:349)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
 at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
 at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
3626 [21704474@qtp-26509496-0] INFO org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect - Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
3640 [21704474@qtp-26509496-0] INFO org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionFactoryFactory - Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
3644 [21704474@qtp-26509496-0] INFO org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionManagerLookupFactory - No TransactionManagerLookup configured (in JTA environment, use of read-write or transactional second-level cache is not recommended)
3644 [21704474@qtp-26509496-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Automatic flush during beforeCompletion(): disabled
3644 [21704474@qtp-26509496-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Automatic session close at end of transaction: disabled
3645 [21704474@qtp-26509496-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Scrollable result sets: disabled
3645 [21704474@qtp-26509496-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - JDBC3 getGeneratedKeys(): disabled
3645 [21704474@qtp-26509496-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Connection release mode: auto
3646 [21704474@qtp-26509496-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Default batch fetch size: 1
3646 [21704474@qtp-26509496-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Generate SQL with comments: disabled
3646 [21704474@qtp-26509496-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Order SQL updates by primary key: disabled
3646 [21704474@qtp-26509496-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Order SQL inserts for batching: disabled
3646 [21704474@qtp-26509496-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Query translator: org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
3651 [21704474@qtp-26509496-0] INFO org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory - Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
3651 [21704474@qtp-26509496-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Query language substitutions: {}
3652 [21704474@qtp-26509496-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - JPA-QL strict compliance: disabled
3652 [21704474@qtp-26509496-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Second-level cache: enabled
3652 [21704474@qtp-26509496-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Query cache: disabled
3664 [21704474@qtp-26509496-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Cache region factory : org.hibernate.cache.impl.bridge.RegionFactoryCacheProviderBridge
3665 [21704474@qtp-26509496-0] INFO org.hibernate.cache.impl.bridge.RegionFactoryCacheProviderBridge - Cache provider: org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider
3666 [21704474@qtp-26509496-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Optimize cache for minimal puts: disabled
3666 [21704474@qtp-26509496-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Structured second-level cache entries: disabled
3678 [21704474@qtp-26509496-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Statistics: disabled
3678 [21704474@qtp-26509496-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Deleted entity synthetic identifier rollback: disabled
3678 [21704474@qtp-26509496-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Default entity-mode: pojo
3679 [21704474@qtp-26509496-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Named query checking : enabled
3775 [21704474@qtp-26509496-0] INFO org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl - building session factory
4155 [21704474@qtp-26509496-0] INFO org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryObjectFactory - Not binding factory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured
4170 [21704474@qtp-26509496-0] INFO org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - Running hbm2ddl schema update
4170 [21704474@qtp-26509496-0] INFO org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - fetching database metadata
4171 [21704474@qtp-26509496-0] ERROR org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - could not get database metadata
java.sql.SQLException: socket creation error
 at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
 at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcConnection.(Unknown Source)
 at org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver.getConnection(Unknown Source)
 at org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:154)
 at org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProvider.java:133)
 at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.java:51)
 at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:168)
 at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:346)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1327)
 at se.kanit.projectmgr.db.HibernateUtil.(HibernateUtil.java:24)
 at se.kanit.web.projectmgr.server.issues.IssuesService.addIssue(IssuesService.java:26)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:100)
 at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:562)
 at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:188)
 at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:224)
 at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:713)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:806)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
 at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:51)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
 at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
 at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:122)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
 at com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:70)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
 at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:349)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
 at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
 at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
4172 [21704474@qtp-26509496-0] ERROR org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - could not complete schema update
java.sql.SQLException: socket creation error
 at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
 at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcConnection.(Unknown Source)
 at org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver.getConnection(Unknown Source)
 at org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:154)
 at org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProvider.java:133)
 at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.java:51)
 at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:168)
 at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:346)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1327)
 at se.kanit.projectmgr.db.HibernateUtil.(HibernateUtil.java:24)
 at se.kanit.web.projectmgr.server.issues.IssuesService.addIssue(IssuesService.java:26)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:100)
 at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:562)
 at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:188)
 at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:224)
 at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:713)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:806)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
 at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:51)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
 at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
 at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:122)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
 at com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:70)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
 at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:349)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
 at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
 at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
4293 [21704474@qtp-26509496-0] WARN org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: -80, SQLState: 08000
4293 [21704474@qtp-26509496-0] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - socket creation error
Cannot open connection
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Cannot open connection
 at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:97)
 at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
 at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:52)
 at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:449)
 at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
 at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:142)
 at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:85)
 at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1353)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:100)
 at org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:342)
 at $Proxy7.beginTransaction(Unknown Source)
 at se.kanit.projectmgr.db.HibernateUtil.saveOrUpdate(HibernateUtil.java:115)
 at se.kanit.web.projectmgr.server.issues.IssuesService.addIssue(IssuesService.java:26)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:100)
 at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:562)
 at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:188)
 at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:224)
 at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:713)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:806)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
 at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:51)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
 at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
 at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:122)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
 at com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:70)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
 at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:349)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
 at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
 at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: socket creation error
 at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
 at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcConnection.(Unknown Source)
 at org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver.getConnection(Unknown Source)
 at org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:154)
 at org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProvider.java:133)
 at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
 ... 49 more
```

Any tips and ideas are greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

Toby.

Comment: +1 to Karl - GAE is the cause of the exception. GAE doesn't allow you to open socket connections, which usually means you can't connect to any database. Disable GAE (its a project preference in Eclipse), and remove all GAE jar files from your project classpath. After that, things should work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the restrictions in detail, but in your stacktrace I see that your running it out of the appengine sdk. I think that might be the problem because their restricting quite a bit on the appengine. 
Maybe you can take a look at this.

Comment: unless he is targeting GAE... In which case he needs to get rid og HSQLDB in favour of the appengine datastore

Answer (score 0):

See my answer here: [GWT + ProcessBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413722/gwt-processbuilder/2413770#2413770) Other answers in the same question provide useful advice as well.

It's not exactly about HSQLDB and GWT, but the cause of the error is the same: Google App Engine doesn't support all Java EE classes. Check the [Will it play in GAE?](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/web/will-it-play-in-app-engine?pli=1) page to know if your particular feature/library is available for GAE.